# vba and XML only need to extract attribute values from certain nodes

Tags: xml, vba

I am new to XML. I have a requirement now where I must extract data from a bunch of XML files. I cannot show the entire XML file, but hopefully someone can show me how to do this. I have read through a lot of forums and blogs and I am just so confused. Here is the XML.

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<docpms>
  <distrib>
  <mrc>    
    <toolsetc>              
      <misc>
        <seqlist>
          <item spinno="02">
            <paratext>Gloves</paratext>
          </item>
          <item spinno="022">
            <paratext>Pail</paratext>
          </item>
          <item spinno="03">
            <paratext>Lanyard</paratext>
          </item>
          <item spinno="07">
            <paratext>Goggles</paratext>
          </item>
```

So, I want to loop through the item nodes that have a spinno attribute and get the text value of the attribute. There are many other item nodes that do not have this attribute, so I think I need to use something like the following VBA.

```html
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Dim xDoc As MSXML2.DOMDocument60
Dim strpath As String
Dim spinAttribute As MSXML2.IXMLDOMAttribute

Public Sub LoadDocument()
strpath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\XML\00\"
Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60
xDoc.validateOnParse = False
If (xDoc.Load(strpath & "1C.xml")) Then
   ' The document loaded successfully.
   ' Now do something intersting.
   DisplayNode xDoc.childNodes, 0
Else
   ' The document failed to load.
   ' See the previous listing for error information.
End If
End Sub

Public Sub DisplayNode(ByRef Nodes As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNodeList, _
   ByVal Indent As Integer)
    Dim strSpin As String
    
   Dim xNode As MSXML2.IXMLDOMNode
   Set xNode = xDoc.selectNodes("/docpms/mrc/toolsetc/misc/seqlist/item")
   

   For Each xNode In Nodes
   Set spinAttribute = xNode.Attributes.getNamedItem("spinno")
    strSpin = spinAttribute.Text
      
   Next xNode
End Sub
```

But when I am stepping through the code, I get a type mismatch on Set xNode = xDoc.selectNodes("/docpms/mrc/toolsetc/misc/seqlist/item") for starters and I am not sure if my for each loop will do what I want. Any help will be appreciated.

Thanks,

David

Comment: You can basically parse your XML file using a regex to get your nodes content.

Comment: Do you mean using something like INSTR to look for the nodes and attributes? I could do that, but I would rather learn to use the DOM to do it the way it was designed to be done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the answer in another forum post on Stack Overflow. Sorry I didn't see this earlier today. Here is the answer [How I can read all Attributes from a XML with VBA?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16538329/how-i-can-read-all-attributes-from-a-xml-with-vba#new-answer) and here is my final code.

```html
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Dim spin As String
  Dim xmlUrl As String
  Dim xmlDoc As New DOMDocument
  Dim n As IXMLDOMNode
  Dim nText As String


  xmlUrl = Environ("USERPROFILE") & "\Documents\Viewer\XML\00\001C.xml"
  xmlDoc.async = False

  If Not xmlDoc.Load(xmlUrl) Then
    MsgBox "XML LOAD ERROR"
  Else

    For Each n In xmlDoc.selectNodes("//misc/seqlist/item")
      spin = n.Attributes.getNamedItem("spinno").Text
        nText = n.Text
    Next

  End If

End Sub
```

This searches for and grabs all of the attribute values that I need.

Thanks,

David

Answer (score 0):

You can use XPath to select only nodes which have that attribute:

```
Dim iNodes, n
Set xDoc = New MSXML2.DOMDocument60

xDoc.validateOnParse = True
xDoc.LoadXML Sheet1.Range("a1").Value 'my testing

xDoc.setProperty "SelectionLanguage", "XPath" '<<<######

'I simplified your XML a bit, so adjust here....
Set iNodes = xDoc.SelectNodes("/docpms/seqlist/item[@spinno]")

Debug.Print iNodes.Length
For Each n In iNodes
    Debug.Print n.Text 'all itens with the spinno attribute
Next n
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Tim. I am just getting started with Xpath. I took the tutorial on W3 schools. It seems like you can do quite a bit with Xpath. I am actually learning it at school and at the same time, a requirement for me to use it at work came up. Wow!